# How to forecast the future values ( test data) by making use of the fitted ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am tried as follows
But problem is all the fitted values are 39

Data : [Test and Train data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14u0SOhp81PkQTl9xO0OvwCr3y3GEVUGO)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related to or even a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414122/).

Comment: Problem didnt fixed

Comment: You asked *How to predict on test test by ARIMA in R*, I gave you a step-by-step answer including the code. What more could you want? If you have a question why an optimal forecast from ARIMA(0,1,0) is the last observed value, take a look at a time series textbook or post a new, specific question. But do you need any further clarification on the questions you have already asked?

Comment: Thank you. I get that